# Convert json output to CSV for AWS API output "client.describe_trusted_advisor_check_result"

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, csv

Convert JSON output to CSV for AWS API output `client.describe_trusted_advisor_check_result`.

I want to convert the output JSON to CSV with script in Python. The output in JSON I get is nested.

`

```
import json
import csv

with open('idcheck.json', 'r') as f:
    json_dict = json.load(f)

# Open new CSV file
with open("output5.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    # Write CSV headers

    # Write data to CSV for each image
    images_data = json_dict['result']['flaggedResources']
    for image in images_data:
        writer.writerow([images_data['status'],
             images_data['region'],
             images_data['resourceId'],
             images_data['isSuppressed']])
```

`

Comment: I am trying some like this import json
import csv

with open('idcheck.json', 'r') as f:
    json_dict = json.load(f)

# Open new CSV file
with open("output5.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    # Write CSV headers

    # Write data to CSV for each image
    images_data = json_dict['result']['flaggedResources']
    for image in images_data:
        writer.writerow([images_data['status'],
                           images_data['region'],
                           images_data['resourceId'],
                           images_data['isSuppressed']])

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of writing code in comments. thanks.